# Prevent malicious users from abusing and spamming unauthenticated open APIs

Tags: javascript, api, rest, security, frontend

Here's a security problem I've encountered a couple of times when building small web-based projects interacting with a REST API service. For example, let's say you're building a casual JavaScript-based game where you want a leaderboard of highscores, so you need to post the scores of users to a database.

The easiest solution would be to build a simple web service, e.g. using PHP, Node.js or Python, that accepts `GET` request and saves the results to a database. Let's imagine the API looks something like this:

`GET https://www.example.com/api/highscore?name=SuperGoat31&score=500`

Creating such an API for posting highscores has some obvious drawbacks. A malicious user could write a three-line piece of PHP code to spam the database full of false results, for example:

```php
for ($i = 0; $i < 100; i++) {
    file_get_contents("https://www.example.com/api/highscore?name=SuperGoat31&score=5000000");
}
```

So, I'm looking for a way to prevent that. This mostly relates to small hobby or hackathon projects that just need some kind of protection that will prevent the most obvious of attacks, not large enterprise applications that need strict security. A couple of things I could think of:

**1. Some form of authentication**

An obvious way to solve this would be to have user accounts and only allow requests from logged-in users. This unfortunately has the drawback of putting up a large barrier for users, who need to get an account first. It would also require building a whole authentication workflow with password recovery and properly encrypting passwords and the like.

**2. One-time token based protection**

Generate a token on the server side and serve that to the user on first load, then only allow requests that serve that specific token. Simple enough, but also very easy to circumvent by finding the requests in a browser web inspector and using that for the three-line PHP script.

**3. Log IP address's and ban when malicious use happens**

This could work, but I feel it's not very privacy friendly. Also, logging IP addresses would require [GDPR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Data_Protection_Regulation) consent from users in Europe. Also doesn't prevent the actual spamming itself so you might to first clean up the mess before you start banning IP addresses.

**4. Use an external service**

There are services that provide solutions to this problem. For example, in the past I've used Google's reCAPTCHA  to prevent malicious use. But that also means integrating an external service, making sure you keep it up to date, concerns about the privacy aspects (esp. regarding a service like reCAPTCHA), etc. It feels a bit much for a weekend project.

**5. Throttle requests**

I feel this is probably the easiest solution that actually works for a bit. This does require some form of IP address logging (which might give the problems stated in 3), but at least you can delete those IP addresses pretty quickly afterwards.

But I'm sure there are other methods I've missed, so I would be curious to see other ways of tackling this problem.

Comment: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/28603/how-to-satisfy-gdprs-consent-requirement-for-ip-logging

Comment: I do not think this is a good fit to Stackoverflow as defined in the [help]'s topic area

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but GET should be used for read only; for adding a result, use POST or PUT

Comment: @JiříBaum sure, that would probably be better from an architectural point of view, but that's not really the point of this question. It's just an illustration of how an API could be abused.

Answer (score 5):

Taking into account all mentioned limitations, I would recommend using a combination of methods:

1. Simple session authentication based on one-time token
2. Script obfuscation
3. Request encryption with integrity control

Example:

```js
let req_obj = {
  user: 'SuperGoat31',
  score: 123456,
  sessionId: '4d2NhIgMWDuzarfAY0qT3g8U2ax4HCo7',
};
req_obj.hash = someCustomHashFunc(JSON.stringify(req_obj));
// now, req_obj.hash = "y0UXBY0rYkxMrJJPdoSgypd"

let req_string = "https://www.example.com/api/cmd?name=" +
                 req_obj.user +
                 "&data=" +
                 Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(req_obj)).toString('base64');

// now, your requests will look like that:
"https://www.example.com/api/cmd?name=SuperGoat31&data=eyJ1c2VyIjoiU3VwZXJHb2F0MzEiLCJzY29yZSI6MTIzNDU2LCJzZXNzaW9uSWQiOiI0ZDJOaElnTVdEdXphcmZBWTBxVDNnOFUyYXg0SENvNyIsImhhc2giOiJ5MFVYQlkwcllreE1ySkpQZG9TZ3lwZCJ9"
```

For casual players, this allows start playing very quickly, as no explicit registration is required. Upon generation, token might be saved as cookie for repetitive use, but this is not necessary, single-time use would also suffice. No personal info gathered.

However, if short-term storage of some client information is an option, the token might be not just some random bytes, but an encrypted string, containing some parameters, such as random salt + IP address + nickname + agent id + etc. In this case you may start silently ignore certain requests from fraudulent clients upon detection.

Obviously, this would be very easy to crack for a professional, but this is not our goal. When such simple methods are mixed with several kilobytes of logic of the game and obfuscated, figuring out how to deal with it would require significant amount of knowledge and time, which might serve as a sufficient barrier.

As it is all about balance between convenience and protection, you may implement some additional scoring logic to detect cheating attempts, like final score cannot end with '0', or cannot be even, etc. This would allow you to count cheating attempts (in addition to counting forged requests) and then estimate efficiency of implemented combination of methods.

Comment: Thanks, this looks to me like a good balance between something that's pretty easy to implement and pretty hard to crack if you're not putting in a lot of effort. Some logic on the backend to check for weird scores would also be useful.

Answer (score 3):

Your list of solutions are mostly mitigations, and they are good ideas if they are your only tools. The list seems pretty exhaustive.

2 major ways to actually *solve* this problem are:

1. Remove the incentive of cheating. There's no point submitting a fake score if you are the only person who can see the score. Think about the purpose of why you even want a global high-score list. Maybe there's another way you can reach your objective that makes it uninteresting (or undesirable) to cheat.
2. Have the server completely manage (or duplicate) the game state. You can't cheat if the server calculates the score. For example, if you're modelling a chess game the server can compute every valid move, preventing clients from submitting moves that wouldn't be possible.

It's possible that for your specific case neither are possible, but if you can't adopt either of these strategies you are stuck to imperfect detection mechanisms.

Comment: Thanks. You're right that the solutions are mostly mitigations indeed. I agree that solving the problem by doing some work on the design (your #1 solution) or duplicating state (#2) is superior. It's just that those solutions might not always be feasible to implement for a hobby project.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that a perfect solution will be elusive because two of
your wishes are, perhaps, contradictory:

"You need to post the scores of users to a database" but... "prevent
the most obvious of attacks" without "Some form of authentication."

The most obvious of attacks are those from users without some form
of authentication.

You wish this system to work without placing an undue burden on
your users. You wish to avoid the usual login and password
authentication which can be cumbersome for users.

I think there is a way to accomplish what you want by creating a
very simple form of authentication by the use of a one-time token
based protection. And I would also incorporate IP tracking against
abuse. In other words, let's combine your options 1 and 2 and 3 in
the following way.

You already have implied that you will maintain a database, and that
within the database, user names will be unique (otherwise you couldn't
record unique high scores). Let people sign up freely by submitting
their requested user name, which you'll accept if not already used
by someone prior. Track the sign-up requests by IP address to detect
and prevent abuse: too many sign-ups from one IP address within a given timeframe. So far, the burden is all at the server end, not on the user.

When you process a valid sign-up (i.e. new user name) into the
database, you will also generate, record into the database, *and* return to the user a shared secret (a token) that will be used by the
Time-based One-time Password (TOTP) algorithm.

Don't reinvent this.

See:

- *[Time-based One-Time Password](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-based_One-Time_Password)*
- *[FreeOTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeOTP)*
- *[OneTimePass](https://github.com/tadeck/onetimepass)*

When you return a token to the user, it will be in the form of a "QR Code"

*[QR code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code)*

which the user will scan and store with his "Google Authenticator" or
equivalent TOTP application.

When the user returns to your web site to update his high score, he
will authenticate himself using his Google Authenticator" or
equivalent TOTP application. These are often used for "second factor"
authentication, 2FA (*[Multi-factor authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-factor_authentication)*), but because
of your need for less strict security, you'll be using the TOTP
authentication as the primary and only form of authentication.

So we have combined a form of authentication which doesn't place a
very high burden on the user (apps already widely available and in
use), with one-time token based protection (provided by the TOTP
app) and a little bit of IP address-based abuse protection for the initial sign-ups.

On of the weaknesses of my proposal is that a user may share his
TOTP token with another person, who may then impersonate him. But this
is no different from the risk of password sharing. And there will
be no "recover my lost password" option.

Comment: Thanks, i think your solution might be a little too much work for the average hackathon / weekend project, but for something that's a bit more professional i would definitely consider something like this. Thanks for all the pointers to articles and documentation!

Answer (score 1):

I would tackle this in a slightly different way: usernames/gamertags. Depending on how frequently you find gamertags and usernames sharing the same IP. So if you only accept a maximum of, say, 5 gamertags per IP, and you also throttle the frequency of updates per gamertag, you have a fairly spam-resistant system.

Comment: Thanks, that seems like a pretty easy solution to implement, and a bit reminiscent of solution 5) in my original post.

Comment: This is more specific and targeted. It's not just blanket throttling, which would have user experience drawbacks.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [reCAPTCHA V2](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display).

Admittedly, v3 provides better protection, but it is hard to implement, so go with v2.

Come on, it is just a few lines of code.

How it should work (according to me):

- You are at the main page willing to play the game
- You solve the reCAPTCHA
- Then the app sends a one-time token with a script tag which establishes a websocket request with your server [(using socket.io)](https://socket.io/) with the one-time token and then it is destroyed immediately (from the server as well as the client) after establishment of a connection
- Your server validates the token and accepts the request of websocket and then it will send the HTML content
- Just create a `div` and set the value using `obj.innerHTML`
- You can use styles in body (I guess)

And the most important point is ***obfuscating your code***.

**Security**

- Websockets are harder to reverse engineer in a test environment
- Even if they create a web socket, it won't respond, because they don't know the one-time token
- It prevents script blocking (as the script loads everything on the page)
- It provides real-time communication
- The only way out is to somehow get your hands on Google's reCAPTCHA token which is impossible, because it means going against Google
- You can’t reuse any token (however immediate it be), because it was destroyed from both the sides
- One more last tip: set a timeout for the one-time token to about 15 seconds
- How will it help? It will prevent someone (extremely malicious) from pausing the Chrome debugger and get the token and put it in their stuff as 15 seconds is ok for slow networks also, but not a human

Comment: Thanks. I have implemented ReCAPTCHA before (and i agree it's not that hard to implement) but i don't like the fact that you need to hand over your users data to a third party. However, using Websockets seems like an interesting solution, so thanks for mentioning that.

Comment: You are welcome, i like recaptcha because it is made by google and evidently breaking it will cause a lot of stuff to break and also you are in a croud of other people

Comment: anyways to impliment hard security you need to track users regardless

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a mix of code obfuscation and using web sockets to request the score, rather than post the score. Something like socket.io (https://socket.io/) where the server sends a request with a code in it and your game responds with the score and that code changed in some way.

Obviously a hacker could look through your code for how your game responds to requests and rewrite it, which is where the obfuscation is important, but it does at least hide the obvious network traffic and prevents them posting scores whenever they feel like it.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't think about using web sockets, but that definitely feels like something that is not too hard to implement and would keep the laziest crackers out of the door.